# How to create string array (with string keys)?

Tags: javascript

Convert this PHP script to Javascript:

```
$ar = array();

// add dynamically new element to string array
$ar['aaa'] = "Hello";
$ar['bbb'] = "World";
$ar['ccc'] = "Test!";

foreach($ar as $key => $val){
   print $key." => ".$val."\n";
}
```

Result will be:

```
aaa => Hello
bbb => World
ccc => Test!
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object instead of array:

```
const obj = {}

obj.aaa = "Hello"
obj.bbb = "World"
obj.ccc = "Test!"

for (const property in obj) {
  console.log(`${property} => ${obj[property]}`)
}
```

Comment: You might want to provide a non-ES6 solution.

Comment: var a = new Array();
a['name'] = 'oscar';
alert(a['name']); this ok ?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Why? You can use Babel to compile this code into non-ES6.

Comment: @Gothdo Most importantly people usually don't expect ES6 code when they tag `javascript` in the question. It might work in some browsers, then they will be surprised that it suddenly stopped working in other browsers. Since OP is asking such simple question I would believe that OP hasn't even heard of ES6 before.

Comment: @waza123 No, there is no "string arrays" in JavaScript. Instead, you create an Object which is similar to an associative array: `var ar = {aaa: "Hello", bbb: "World", ccc: "Test!"};` Please read [the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) that I have posted for more information on Objects.